# Finding a way to handle colors and powers on a board game

Tags: java, hierarchy

I am creating a game for my school project, so I am not here for any kind of code, just a global idea on how to do what I am trying to do...

I have Pieces and each piece as is own color and Type like this :
Piece 1 - Yellow - Simple
Piece 2 - Yellow - Explosive
....
Piece 10 - Blue - ChangeColor

At start the game will be field with random pieces from this list (a list created earlier with  just one kind of each piece), if we have 3 or more in a row the game as to remove them and count the points, but if one of the 3 (or more) has any "power effect" than the pieces arround must react to that power (hard to explain with my low english level but I think you got it :S..)

For now my game only had simple pieces, and for that I used and enum like this :

```
public enum CorPeca 
{    
     AMARELO,
     AZUL,
     VERMELHO;
}
```

On the board class I was doing this :

```
    this.arrayPecas = new ArrayList<Peca>();

    for (CorPeca corPeca : CorPeca.values())
        this.arrayPecas.add(new Peca(corPeca));
```

and on the Pieces class i was doing this

```
public Peca(CorPeca tipoPeca)
{
    this.definirPeca(tipoPeca);
}

public CorPeca getCorPeca() { return this.corPeca; }
public char getCharPeca() { return this.charPeca; }

public void definirPeca(CorPeca tipoPeca)
{
    switch (tipoPeca)
    {
        case AMARELO:
            this.charPeca = 'a';
            this.corPeca = CorPeca.AMARELO;
            break;
        case AZUL:
            this.charPeca = 'u';
            this.corPeca = CorPeca.AZUL;
            break;
        case VERMELHO:
            this.charPeca = 'e';
            this.corPeca = CorPeca.VERMELHO;
            break;                
    }
}
```

But I was thinking of a good method to easily add those "Power Pieces", but more than that, being able to add more colors and more "Powers" in the future...

I was thinking about creating subclasses and using extend, but the whole idea just don't fill in my mind since we can't extends several classes...

So can anyone give me a global idea on how I can archive that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic OOP way to do this would be to define an abstract base class that represents all pieces and contains common functionality (such as a list of powers):

```
public abstract class Piece {
    // put in fields that every piece has, e.g. x and y co-ordinate here

    // array of powers
    protected ArrayList<Power> powers=new ArrayList<Power>();

    // method to add new powers to the piece
    public void addPower(Power power) {
        powers.add(power);
    }

    // power method - optionally overriden by specififc pieces
    public void applyPowers() {
        for (Power power:powers) {
            power.methodToActivatePower();
        }
    }

    // abstract char method
    public abstract char getChar();

}
```

Note that `abstract` means that you can't directly instantiate this class - you can only make instances of concrete subclasses.

Then extend this class to implement each specific piece:

```
public class YellowPiece extends Piece {

    // override applyPowers for yellow piece (if needed)
    @Override
    public void applyPowers() {
        // code for yellow piece power handling goes here
    }

    // override char - required
    @Override
    public char getChar() {
        return 'y';
    }

}
```

You can still create an `ArrayList<Piece>` and populate it with something like:

```
ArrayList<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();
pieces.add (new YellowPiece());
pieces.add (new GreenPiece());
// etc....
```

Then if you want to apply the power of a specific piece, just do:

```
pieces.get(pieceNumber).applyPower();
```

You'll obviously need to customise this code a lot to make it work in your game, but hopefully it gives you the general idea. Note that there are lots of other ways of achieving the same goals - I've just described the "classic" OOP way.

P.S. Apologies for all code being in English, but your English is far better than my Portugese :-)

Comment: You forgot to specify that `YellowPiece extends Piece`. You should also add `@Override` annotations as good practice.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help ! Really ^^ (PS: It's portuguese not spanish, it's a common mistake no problem xD).

Just one question, your coding is saying that every color has a especific power no ? How can i define then a diferent power ?

Comment: @aliasbody - ah OK perhaps I misunderstood the point of the powers.... if a piece can have multiple powers then you can add a `powers` arraylist within Piece. Then Power can itself be an abstract class that has multiple subclasses for different power types. then you can do something like `piece.addPower(new ExplosionPower());` etc. hopefully that makes sense? will do some quick edits to the answer

Comment: So if i understand it well i will have 2 "superclasses" pieces and powers (for example) and each will have their respective subclasse Yellow, Blue etc.. for Piece and Explosion, ChangeCOlor etc... for power. 

Now I just have to find a way, and adapt the code, so that I could connect it to my board class in order to make the power activates and reproduces is effects on the game.

I had the same idea just didn't know how to apply it (because of the abstract vs subclasses thing), now all that makes a lot of sense to me ^^ Thank you !

Comment: @aliasbody - sounds like you've got it - good luck making it all work and have fun!

Comment: @mikera one last question.. In my old code I had a foreach for the enum list that would create all the pieces in that color, i thought of creating a new enum for all the powers, but since I won't use the enums anymore, i wanted to continue to have that kind of code.. So, is there a way to initialize all the colors and powers without having to declare them manualy ? (even when more colors and more powers are added, and without chaning the original code ?)

Comment: @mikera here piece.addPower(new ExplosionPower()); it says 'void' type not allowed here :S How can I solve this problem ?